# getting error trying to insert data into the database

Tags: c#

i was trying to insert data into the database and i am getting some error.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;//provide all the classes of the sql
using System.Configuration;
public partial class registration : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsPostBack)
        {
         SqlConnection conn=new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["registrationConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
         conn.Open();
        string checkuser = "select count(*) from user where username='" + TextBoxun.Text + "'";
         SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(checkuser,conn);
         int temp = Convert.ToInt32(com.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
         if (temp == 1)
         {
             Response.Write("user already exists");
         }

         conn.Close();
        }

    }

    protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["registrationConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
            conn.Open();
            string insertquery = " insert into user (username,email,password,country) values (@uname,@email,@password,@country) ";
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(insertquery, conn);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uname", TextBoxun.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", TextBoxemail.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", TextBoxpw.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@country", DropDownListcn.SelectedItem.ToString());
            com.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Response.Redirect("manager.aspx");
            Response.Write("registration is successful");
            conn.Close();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write("error:" + ex.ToString());
        }

    }
}
```

and the error i am getting is

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'user'.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'user'.

Source Error:


Line 17:         string checkuser = "select count(*) from user where username='" + TextBoxun.Text + "'";
Line 18:          SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(checkuser,conn);
Line 19:          int temp = Convert.ToInt32(com.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
Line 20:          if (temp == 1)
Line 21:          {


Source File: c:\Users\Admin\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\WebSites\learn1\registration.aspx.cs    Line: 19

Stack Trace:


[SqlException (0x80131904): Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'user'.]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +1753346
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +5295154
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) +242
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) +1682
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData() +59
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData() +90
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString) +365
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite) +1325
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite) +175
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method) +53
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar() +149
   registration.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Users\Admin\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\WebSites\learn1\registration.aspx.cs:19
   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +51
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +92
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +54
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +772


Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.17929
```

i searched for the error in internet but i didn't get the proper answer.

Comment: user is a reserved word in SQL

Comment: [GENTLEMEN, SANITIZE YOUR DATA INPUTS](http://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: (Side comment - do NOT EVER put text that the user has entered into your sql statement. You are setting yourself up for an sql injection attack)

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: Bobby Tables has got to be the most over-posted Link on Stackoverflow comments ever.

Answer (score 4):

`User` is a reserve word. So surround the `User` in your SQL with `[..]` like so.

```
string checkuser = "select count(*) from [user] where username='" + TextBoxun.Text + "'";
```

Also parameterize your `TextBoxun.Text` to avoid SQL Injection attacks. i.e. like the following.

```
string checkuser = "select count(*) from [user] where username= @UserName ";, connection))
  // Add new SqlParameter to the command.
  //
 com .Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@UserName", TextBoxun.Text));
```

Finally, you should enclose the `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` objects in a `Using` block so resources are automatically disposed at the end.

Answer (score 1):

This

```
string checkuser = "select count(*) from user where username='" + TextBoxun.Text + "'";
```

To this:

```
string checkuser = "select count(*) from [user] where username='" + TextBoxun.Text + "'";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;

using System.Collections.Generic;

using System.Linq;

using System.Web;

using System.Web.UI;

using System.Web.UI.WebControls;


using System.Data.SqlClient;//provide all the classes of the sql

using System.Configuration;

namespace Registerpage

{

    public partial class Registerwebpage : System.Web.UI.Page

    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)

        {
            if (IsPostBack)

            {

                SqlConnection conn = new           SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegisterConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
                conn.Open();
                string checkuser = "select count(*) from [Table1] where Username='" + TextBoxUN.Text + "'";
                SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(checkuser, conn);
                Int32 count = Convert.ToInt32(com.ExecuteScalar().ToString());


                if (count == 1)
                {
                    Response.Write("user already exists");
                }

                conn.Close();
            }
        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegisterConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
                conn.Open();
                string insertquery = " insert into [Table1] (username,email,password,country) values (@uname,@email,@password,@country) ";
                SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(insertquery, conn);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uname", TextBoxUN.Text);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", TextBoxEmail.Text);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", TextBoxPass.Text);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@country", DropDownListCountry.SelectedItem.ToString());
                com.ExecuteNonQuery();
                Response.Redirect("RegisterDatabase.aspx");
                Response.Write("registration is successful");
                conn.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Response.Write("error:" + ex.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain *why* your code solves the problem? Please, see [answer].